# Adding validations on class fields in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, validation

I have a class Customers. I want to put some validations on it.
e.g. CustGuidId is not Guid.Empty, CustName is NOT NULL (Required).

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustId;
    public string CustName;
    public Guid CustGuid;
    public Guid[] OrderGuids;
}
```

I have such collection of customers. So I have ended up adding code like this, which makes it look ugly.

```
public class BatchError
{
    public int Index;
    public string ErrorCode;
    public string ErrorMessage;
}


public void GenerateValidationErrors(List<Customer> customers, out List<BatchError> batchErrors)
    {
        int rowNum = 0;
        batchErrors = new List<BatchError>(customers.Count);

        foreach (var customer in customers)
        {
            rowNum ++;
            Guid customerGuidParsed;
            if(!Guid.TryParse(customer.CustGuid.ToString(), out customerGuidParsed))
            {
                batchErrors.Add(new BatchError { Index = rowNum, ErrorCode = "CustomerGuidcannotBeNull", ErrorMessage = "Customer guid cannot be null." });
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(customer.CustName))
            {
                batchErrors.Add(new BatchError { Index = rowNum, ErrorCode = "CustomerNamecannotBeEmpty", ErrorMessage = "Customer Name cannot be empty." });
            }
        }
    }
```

Can we write separate validator classes, like GuidValidator, StringValidator.
and Create array of delegates & chain their invokes ?

```
(Customer c) => new GuidValidator(c.CustGuid.toString()),
(Customer c) => new StringValidator(c.CustName.toString())
```

But what design pattern would be best suitable for this scenario?

Is there any other way to add validations in WCF?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do the validation. I prefer to validate `DataContract` itself before any action. 
It can also be done in many like :

- `DatamemberAttribute` has many properties. One of them is
  `IsRequired`,it controls the minOccurs attribute for the schema
  element. The default value is false. You can use it like:

  `[DataContract(Name ="Place", Namespace ="")]
   public class DataContractExample
   {
        [DataMember(IsRequired=true)]
        public string DataMemberExample;
   }`

For more information refer: [DataMemberAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on MSDN.

- Easiest way is to validate property like:

  `[DataContract]
  public class Customer
  {
      [DataMember]
      public string CustName
      {
         get
         { 
              return this._custName;
         }
         set
         {
              if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) 
                 throw new MyValidationException();
              else
                 this._custName=value;
         }
      }
  }`
- Another way can be to use **Microsoft Enterprise Library**. In order to enable validation of the properties of a request message, you only need to add a `[ValidationBehavior]` attribute to your service interface, just next (or before) the `[ServiceContract]`, and a `[FaultContract(typeof(ValidationFault))]` on the method declaration. The `ValidationBehaviorAttribute` and `ValidationFault` classes are defined in the `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Integration.WCF` assembly and are part of the Validation Application Block of the Enterprise Library 4.1, more specifically, of the WCF integration module. See full implementation in detail at: http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/validation-of-wcf-requests-with-the-enterprise-library-validation-block
- Finally one more solution cane be to use WCF Data Annotations  from  http://wcfdataannotations.codeplex.com/. Using this you can use validations like:

  ```
  [DataMember]
  [Required]
  [StringLength(500, MinimumLength = 5)]
  public string Description{ get; set; }
  ```

Choose which ever suite your requirements. Cheers.